# Obtaining the User List of an Azure Resource Group Using Python

Tags: python, azure, identity-management

I'm the owner of an Azure resource group and I need to manage it. To do this, I need to keep track of the various users who have roles in this resource group, and delete them if they are no longer part of my organization. I'd like to automate this action with python.

How can I get the name and e-mail address of the various users in my resource group?

How can I then delete them directly with python too?

Answer (score 0):

Create an **Azure AD application and grant below API permissions**:

[image]

**To get the app role assignments of the principal type of user at the resource group scope make use of below code:**

```py
import requests
import json

tenant_id = 'TenantID'
client_id = 'ClientID'
client_secret = 'ClientSecret'
scope = 'https://management.azure.com/.default'

# Azure AD OAuth 2.0 token endpoint
token_endpoint = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{}/oauth2/v2.0/token'.format(tenant_id)

token_request_params = {
   'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
   'client_id': client_id,
   'client_secret': client_secret,
   'scope': scope
}

# Send OAuth 2.0 token request
token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=token_request_params)
token_response_json = json.loads(token_response.text)
access_token = token_response_json['access_token']

# Use the access token to authenticate to Azure Management API
headers = {
   'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token),
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.get(url='https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SubscriptionID/resourceGroups/ruk/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?api-version=2022-04-01', headers=headers)

print(response.status_code)

json_data = json.loads(response.text)

# Iterate through role assignments and print only the principalId
for role_assignment in json_data['value']:
   if 'properties' in role_assignment and 'scope' in role_assignment['properties'] and 'principalType' in role_assignment['properties'] and role_assignment['properties']['scope'] == '/subscriptions/SubscriptionID/resourceGroups/ruk' and role_assignment['properties']['principalType'] == 'User':
       # Extract and print the principalId
       principal_id = role_assignment['properties']['principalId']
       print(principal_id)
```

[image]

> **Note** that: To fetch the app role assignments of the users at the resource group scope, you have to generate access token for  **`https://management.azure.com/.default`** scope and to fetch the if the user's are deactivated and delete them you have to make a different API call that is generate access token for  **`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`**

**To fetch and delete the users if the user is deactivated, make use of below code:**

```py
import requests
import json

tenant_id = 'TenantID'
client_id = 'ClientID'
client_secret = 'ClientSecret'
scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'

# Azure AD OAuth 2.0 token endpoint
token_endpoint = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{}/oauth2/v2.0/token'.format(tenant_id)

token_request_params = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'scope': scope
}

# Send OAuth 2.0 token request
token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=token_request_params)
token_response_json = json.loads(token_response.text)
access_token = token_response_json['access_token']

# Use the access token to authenticate to Azure Management API
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

# List of user Object IDs
user_object_ids = ['UserID1', 'UserID2', 'UserID3']

# Iterate through each user
for user_object_id in user_object_ids:
    # Make a request for each user
    response = requests.get(
        url=f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_object_id}?$select=DisplayName,accountEnabled',
        headers=headers
    )

    if response.status_code == 200:
        json_data = json.loads(response.text)
        account_enabled = json_data.get('accountEnabled', False)

        if not account_enabled:
            # Delete the user using the specified DELETE query
            delete_response = requests.delete(
                url=f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_object_id}',
                headers=headers
            )

            print(f"\nUser Object ID: {user_object_id}")
            print("Account Enabled: False. User deleted. Response Status Code:", delete_response.status_code)
        else:
            print(f"\nUser Object ID: {user_object_id}")
            print("Account Enabled: True. User not deleted.")
    else:
        print("Error:", response.text)
```

[image]

You have to assign either User Administrator, Privileged Authentication Administrator or Global Administrator to the application to perform the delete operation. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).